# Convert mp3 into byte array and display byte array as image

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio, mp3

I am trying to take an mp3 in my Android Studio application and convert it into a byte array. Then I am trying to take the byte array and convert it into an image and display it in an imageview.

```
public class ConvertMp3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_convert_mp3);


}


public static byte[] convertStreamToByteArray(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buff = new byte[10240];
    int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    while ((i = is.read(buff, 0, buff.length)) > 0) {
        baos.write(buff, 0, i);
    }


    return baos.toByteArray(); // be sure to close InputStream in calling function

}

public void selectMp3(View view) throws IOException
{

    MediaPlayer ring = MediaPlayer.create(ConvertMp3Activity.this,R.raw.testsong);
    ring.start();

    InputStream inStream = getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.testsong);

    byte[] music = new byte[inStream.available()];

        music = convertStreamToByteArray(inStream);
        Log.i("worked", music.toString());



    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(music, 0, music.length);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);

    inStream.close();





}
```

The media player above was just to check that the mp3 was in the right format, as you can see it is just a resource file in the raw folder. In the Log output i get the following I/worked: [B@d5fccc. I am new to android studio (Doing a university project). I am pretty sure that the byte array is incorrect but I cant work out why. Also when I try and convert it into an image and display it, it simply shows nothing in the image view. I am trying to display the image as a kind of WAV graph. [Expected Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTAtj.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have also allowed permissions to read external storage in the manifest.

Comment: it won;t display a wav graph just by setting the bytes as the image. Search for `how to get a wave form in Android`

Comment: Thank you, will have a look :)

Answer (score 0):

An MP3 file is an audio file. It is not an image file. `BitmapFactory` cannot produce a waveform graph from an MP3 file. `BitmapFactory` can decode bitmaps (PNG, JPEG, WebP), nothing more.

There are several audio visualizer libraries such as [this](https://github.com/GautamChibde/android-audio-visualizer), [this](https://github.com/wotomas/droid-vizu), and [this](https://github.com/Taishi-Y/MusicIndicator). Perhaps you can adapt one of them to fit your needs.

Comment: Perfect thanks I will have a look. Just for interest sake is the way that I am converting the MP3 into a byte array correct ?

Comment: @NicholasMott: Well, since `BitmapFactory` has `decodeResource()` and `decodeStream()` methods, reading in the MP3 file into a `byte[]` is unnecessary (besides wasting heap space). Usually I see `int i = 0;` instead of `int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE;`. Otherwise, what you have there should be OK, though I am short on sleep right now, so I may be missing something.

Comment: No worries, thank you so much, just trying to learn as much as possible :)